# getting folder paths in bash scripts to work on windows

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell, path

I have a script that usually works in linux, but I'm trying to make it work on windows as well.

The script basically calls some other programs, and then moves lots of files.

The problem is that all the pathing is done using normal slashes (`/`), but when I try to run the script using `cmder`, like `sh path/to/script/script.sh param` it's failing to find stuff because it ends up mixing slashes: `Unable to access jarfile C:\full\path\to\file/here/are/normal/slashes/javafile.jar` and so on.

Say, when I edited the java files to work with both OS pathing, I changed the concating of slashes to the use of `java.nio.file.Paths.get` to get a correct path.

Is there a way to do something like that on bash?

f.e. if i have `jarpath=../path/to/jar`, to something like `jarpath=correct_os_path(../path/to/jar)`

Comment: Windows understand forward slashes. Can you change your script into something like `/full/path/to/file/here/are/normal/slashes/javafile.jar` ?

Comment: the thing is that I want the script to work on both windows and linux, and I don't want to maintain two scripts.

Answer (score 1):

To change the slashes to correct type for the OS, try:

```
fixpath() {
    case "$OSTYPE" in
        *(linux|darwin|bsd)*) echo "${1//\\/\/}" ;;
        *win*) echo "${1//\//\\}" ;;
    esac
}
```

The above a bash function called `fixpath`.  The function uses bash's `OSTYPE` variable to determine the OS and then uses bash's *pattern substitution* to change slashes to backslashes or vice versa.

For example, when run on Linux:

```
$ fixpath '\a\b\c/d/e'
/a/b/c/d/e
```

In your use case:

```
jarpath="$(fixpath "../path/to/jar")"
```

#### Limitation

On Unix, it is possible for a file or directory name to contain a literal `\`.  For the Unix-Windows conversion to work reliably, try to avoid such names.

Comment: Hey dude, I don't seem to have that `OSTYPE` variable. I've added a default case that echos "hello world" and I do in fact get hello world. Also, the parentheses in `(linux|darwin|bsd)` emit a syntax error, so I dropped them.

Comment: @GioraGuttsait  From what you are telling me, you are not using `bash`.  On the linux side, which distribution are you using? How are you invoking the shell script?  From the command prompt, run `echo $OSTYPE` and let me know what the response is.